# How to stop an infinite iterator on the first None value?

Tags: rust, iterator

I don't know why in the below code the iteration is not stopped in the first encountered `None` (after reaching the empty range `0..0`)

```rust
fn main() {
    let iter = (0..)
        .flat_map(move |i| if i < 10 { (0..i).into_iter() } else { 0..0 })
        .fuse();
    for i in iter {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=492a013967f4f11de2565a32ffd43a65) reports that it had to be killed, why would it not stop? How to make it stop?

Comment: "I don't know why in the below code the iteration is not stopped in the first encountered None" - because that's not how iterators/loops work. You want to break on `None`, you could match on `i` in the loop explicitly.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, thanks for the info. but, how do the iterator knows when it is exhausted then?

Comment: When its [`next`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) returns None. Which is different from it returning Some(None)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, uhm, yeah, makes sense, But that iterator returns `Item=usize`, so, when reaching the `0..0` (as IntoIterator) and having nothing to return it should return a `None` on the `next` call when reaching that IntoIterator one.

Comment: Ah, I see. Indeed, my bad. Let me think.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, look this variant of the example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=56bcbbb09d874712b1cda0864c4e7c41
Super weird, it is like it gets stuck when reaching to what it should be `None`

Comment: Ah, sorry, got distracted. The mistake in your logic seem to be in "flattening an empty range should return None". It returns an empty sequence instead. `flat_map` then passes nothing over to `fuse` and instead just pops the next element from the source (the endless range).

Comment: Aaaah, yeah. Uhm, ok, I'll try to get what should I return instead of the empty range so it actually stops there. Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: It's best not to conflate the two operations: limiting intake and transforming elements. I'd split them like so: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=31aa299196c3564734ce43179990628a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`flat_map()` is the wrong tool for this task. It is designed to flatten an iterator of iterators, i.e. whenever it encounters `None` on an inner iterator, its *job* is to switch to the next iterator. If you keep feeding it empty iterators, it will keep looping until it finds a non-empty one to deliver values from. `flat_map()` will only terminate iteration when the *outer* iterator does, which in your case never happens.

What you need is two things: first, mark the end of iteration in some way other than an empty iterator - e.g. by using an `Option` where `Some` means "here is another iterator for you" and `None` means "I'm no longer interested in iteration, you can terminate". Second, you need to terminate the iteration *before* the flattening step, using an adapter with the capacity to do so, such as [`take_while()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) or [`scan()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan).

Here is a modification of your code that terminates after `i` reaches 10:

```
fn main() {
    let iter = (0..)
        .map(move |i| if i < 10 { Some(0..i) } else { None })
        .scan((), |_, item| item)
        .flatten();
    for i in iter {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=73774f55e2231092217679556bbc2b2e)

Here the `flat_map()` is broken into three parts: first a `map()` that produces `Some(inner_iterator)` while we want to iterate, and `None` when we no longer do. Then comes `scan()` that transforms the iterator into one whose `next()` just returns the values returned by the closure. Since the closure returns `item` (inner iterator wrapped in an option) unchanged, `Some(inner_iterator)` will pass through, and `None` will be propagated as the end-of-iteration signal. Finally, `flatten()` funnels the items produced by inner iterators into a single iterator, as `flat_map()` did in your original code.

And if you really want to terminate on the first inner iterator that is empty, that can be arranged as well, by extracting the first value in `scan()` and testing it:

```
// using 1.. to avoid immediately terminating on 0..0
let iter = (1..)
    .map(move |i| if i < 10 { 0..i } else { 0..0 })
    .scan((), |_, mut inner| match inner.next() {
        Some(first) => Some(once(first).chain(inner)),
        None => None,
    })
    .flatten();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=336d640a040a62ddbee4a0b30bf1a662)

Note that `fuse()` is not what you want in any of this. Its purpose is to allow the iterator to be safely queried after exhaustion. Normally an iterator could panic if you call `next()` after it has already returned `None`. `fuse()` extends the iterator contract to allow calling `next()` after it has already returned `None`. This is implemented with a separate flag along the inner iterator, and a check of that flag in `next()`. If you don't query the iterator after it has returned `None`—which a `for` loop doesn't—then you have no need for `fuse()`.

Answer (score 4):

From @user4815462342 answer I modified to something that makes it a bit clearer for me:

```rust
    let iter = (0..)
        .map(move |i| if i < 10 { Some(0..i) } else { None })
        .take_while(Option::is_some)
        .flat_map(Option::unwrap);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=19c74d207d779f3dc4af99569687c9ab)

Comment: This is indeed a bit more approachable than `scan()` and equivalent in functionality. The only downside is that it gives off the impression that it could panic on `unwrap()`, which is in fact not the case (a `None` value will never reach `flat_map`). The nice thing about `scan()` is that it allows you to _both_ stop the iteration and transform the item (which `take_while` cannot do because you only get a reference to the item).